# Ubuntu 16.04 boots to purple screen after installing GeForce GTX 960 Drivers

Tags: drivers, 16.04, nvidia-geforce

I'm past my 3rd install now, willing to give 1 more try to install.

Hardware

- Intel i5-6600k
- Msi z170a m7
- Evga GeForce GTX 960 SSC GGDR5 PCI-E
- Samsung SM951 M.2 Pci-e

Last guide tried:
[Getting GeForce GTX960 to work with Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/725820/getting-geforce-gtx960-to-work-with-ubuntu)

Both answers there did not help, the second answer says add nomodeset using program boot-repair which I can't understand how to do. Used nomodeset and blacklisting before, just haven't stopped the gui using light dm.

Problem: Without installing drivers, Ubuntu has a background with different shades of purple. No icons etc, which led to 3 attempts of different variations of nvidia driver installations. The drivers get updated to nvidia, reboot, get the encryption password box come up and the mouse cursor stops working. The keyword works but you cannot type in the box.

Reboot, go into bios, mouse doesn't work still, continue to boot ubuntu after selecting from boot menu. Now it just has plain purple screen.

Reboot and go into safemode, go into the command root and it has a freak out and the screen gets pixel lag and you can't see what's happening.

I am looking for a definitive guide to getting this working. Don't skip anything as I am a complete noob. Don't link me to a guide, chances are I have read it! Please, please help me, you can understand the frustration of this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting GeForce GTX960 to work with Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/725820/getting-geforce-gtx960-to-work-with-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

You could try installing the System76 driver. I have a Nvidia GeForce GTX970m graphics card on my laptop, and the regular Nvidia drivers also cause the purple screen you are describing. Sometimes Nvidia and Ubuntu do not get along well.

http://docs.system76.com/articles/upgrade/

`sudo apt purge nvidia*`

`rm ~/.Xauthority ~/.ICEauthority ~/.config/monitors.xml`

Reboot your machine, then:

`sudo apt-add-repository ppa:system76-dev/stable`

`sudo apt update`

`sudo apt install system76-driver-nvidia`

Reboot again, see if it works.

Comment: So after installing system 76, I do not need to install nvidia drivers?

Comment: If I understand correctly, the system 76 drivers include their own drivers for nvidia graphics cards, so you shouldn't have to install any extra nvidia drivers.

Comment: Ok, any ideas how to remove the current nvidia drivers, fed up of reinstalling. I go into safe mode, drop to root by clicking and hitting enter. I get 30 seconds to purge before sys freezes, but I'm stuck in read only? How to get out of read only so I can run the commands?

Comment: Maybe try using the `sudo apt purge nvidia*` command while in a root shell prompt (access from grub menu). http://askubuntu.com/questions/92556/how-do-i-boot-into-a-root-shell

Comment: Thank you, so I installed it and it didn't work, same problem. `rm ~/.Xauthority ~/.ICEauthority ~/.config/monitors.xml` directories didn't exist btw, same purple screen. Extra info, hdmi causes black screen from computer boot, my dvi-hdmi causes purple screen.